# How do I create an Azure CosmosDB account with the Gremlin Graph API from the Azure CLI?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

In [the tutorial on using Azure CosmosDB as a graph database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-dotnet), they create the database account using the portal.

I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing with the Azure CLI, but reading [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb?view=azure-cli-latest#az-cosmosdb-create) I still can't figure out how to pass the `--capabilities` parameter to enable the Gremlin Graph API.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"EnableGremlin" is the capability name to enable the Gremlin Graph API.

`az cosmosdb create -g <resource-group-name> -n <database-account-name> --capabilities EnableGremlin`